# Input type="file" for each record within a single form is always null ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a form that based on various options such as order cost, etc.., will generate a list of required documentation. This list would allow the end user to upload the appropriate file and then click "upload all". The problem is, when binding the view model back to the action, the upload is always null, but all other fields are correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5M87.png)

Razor page:

```
<form asp-action="UploadQuotes" class="quoteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{                
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id"/>

    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action itemClass">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select asp-for="@Model[i].SelectedType" class="form-control custom-select" asp-items="@Model[i].Options"></select>

                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].SelectedType" text-danger" style="color:red;"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model[i].Upload" type="file" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 my-auto">
                @if (Model[i].AllowDelete)
                {
                    <button class="btn ms-0 ps-0" title="Delete" onclick="jQueryAjaxDelete('@Url.Action("DeleteQuote", "Actions", new {id = Model[i].Id })',this)"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i></button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadQuotes(List<QuoteVM> vm)
{
    foreach(var quote in vm)
    {
        var quotePlaceholder = await _unitOfWork.quoteRepo
                                                .GetByIdAsync(x => x.Id == quote.Id);

        var file = _baseFactory.ConvertUpload(quote.Upload); //returns tuple with upload as byte[]
        quotePlaceholder.Doc = file.Item4;

        _unitOfWork.quoteRepo.Update(quotePlaceholder);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWhzL.png)

Comment: What's your QuoteVM  model? And what's s your jQueryAjaxPost(this) ? Could you share it ? If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: I test your code and select the file and I can get the upload like:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMBEm.png

Comment: Rather than having multiple file-inputs, why not just have `<input type="file" multiple>`?

Answer (score 0):

-> Follow modify code :-

-> Razor Page :-

```
<form asp-action="UploadQuotes" class="quoteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{                
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Id"/>

    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action itemClass">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select asp-for="@Model[i].SelectedType" class="form-control custom-select" asp-items="@Model[i].Options"></select>

                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].SelectedType" text-danger" style="color:red;"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="@Model[i].Upload" name="uploads" type="file" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 my-auto">
                @if (Model[i].AllowDelete)
                {
                    <button class="btn ms-0 ps-0" title="Delete" onclick="jQueryAjaxDelete('@Url.Action("DeleteQuote", "Actions", new {id = Model[i].Id })',this)"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i></button>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
}
<input type="submit" value="Upload All" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

-> Controller :-

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadQuotes(List<QuoteVM> vm, List<IFormFile> uploads)
{
    foreach(var quote in vm)
    {
        var quotePlaceholder = await _unitOfWork.quoteRepo
                                                .GetByIdAsync(x => x.Id == quote.Id);

        // You can process each uploaded file here
        foreach(var file in uploads)
        {
            if(file.Length > 0)
            {
                using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    quotePlaceholder.Doc = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        _unitOfWork.quoteRepo.Update(quotePlaceholder);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

-> In the Razor page input file name="uploads" attribute set, which match parameter name(uploads)in controller.

-> in Controller action method in parameter uploads of type List to receive uploaded file